# Show list of MongoDB documents based on level with Java Recursive

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to get a list of MongoDB documents using Java.
I can get it to a list, but the document are separated, I want them to be listed as a tree.

For example, here is what I can get:

```
"data": [
        {
            "categoryLevel": 1,
            "categoryName": "Electronics",
            "categoryId": "1001"
        },
        {
            "categoryLevel": 2,
            "categoryName": "Air Conditioner",
            "categoryId": "1002"
        },
        {
            "categoryLevel": 3,
            "categoryName": "Refrigerator",
            "categoryId": "1003"
        }
    ]
```

And here is what I want it to be:

```
level 1
|
|--level 2
|
|--level 2
|
|--|
   |--level 3
```

I was suggested using the recursion but I do not know how to do it, please help me.

Pretending all the query statements existed.

*Edit: In case you want to look at my code.
Here:

```
JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
List<ProductCategory> categories = null;
if (!GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(categoryId)) {
    categories = getProductCategoryController().getProductCategories(new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(categoryId)));
} else {
    categories = getProductCategoryController().getProductCategoriesByOrgId(getOrgEcomosId());
}
if (type.equals("list")) {
    if (null != categories && categories.size() > 0) {
        JSONArray listCategories = new JSONArray();
        categories.forEach(t -> {
            JSONObject category = new JSONObject();
            category.put("categoryLevel", t.getLevel());
            category.put("categoryName", t.getName());
            category.put("categoryId", t.getId());
            listCategories.put(category);
        });
        result = new JSONObject();
        result.put("data", listCategories);
        result.put("status", 1);
    }
}
return result(result);
```

Comment: Note: This is an API with @GET method, above code will show a list when param "list" is provided, I am trying to get a tree list like the example above when param "tree" is provided.